# how to detach alternates after git clone --reference?

Tags: git, clone

I'm using `git clone --reference` to reduce network traffic over a slow connection.

Now, `git-clone`'s man page points out the dangers of using this and suggests `git repack -a` to break the link, which I'm doing immediately after the clone.

What I'd like to know is - after I've done the repack, is it then safe to just delete `.git/objects/info/alternates` or is there a proper git command to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

OK, so I found out. The answer is yes, it is safe to delete alternates directly. And no, there is no git command to do this.

http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/141161/focus=141199

I know it's not the done thing to answer your own question, but we have to move on!

Comment: FYI, [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: If fact, I'm grateful you recorded the answer rather than just moving on.

Answer (score 34):

Note that `git clone` now has a new `--dissociate` option that does this. It was added in Git 2.3: https://github.com/blog/1957-git-2-3-has-been-released

The option simply calls `git repack -a -d` and deletes `.git/objects/info/alternates`. So yes, it is safe. (Source: https://github.com/gitster/git/commit/d35c8027937546e6b22a2f28123f731c84e3b380)

Comment: If you are using Git LFS, `--dissociate` will prevent the clone from retrieving LFS objects and cause an error. You will need to do `git clone --reference` as usual and perform the manual steps of running `git repack -a -d` and deleting the `alternates` file. For non-LFS repos, this answer is the best supported way to do it.

Comment: @Phil Is there any explanation why? I'm curious, I looked at the source code for dissociate, and it looks like it really just does the equivalent of those two commands, so in theory there shouldn't be any difference. Though the code for deleting file (unlink) looks like it will abort after enough failed attempts (https://github.com/git/git/blob/3034dab9ed6b11970a53099a7b3ca981f1461365/compat/mingw.c#L262) But I'm not really sure if that's what's making it different.

Comment: @AnomalousUnderdog Sorry, I've slept a few hundred times since I wrote that comment.... It feels like I've seen this question for the first time and it's all Greek to me. _Man_ Git is complex...

Comment: @Phil ah, no worries, at least doing it manually still works (I was doing it just a few hours ago). Better safe than sorry :)